# iOS: TabBarController with two sub-views?

Tags: ios, view, tabs

In my app, I want two modes that the user can choose from, using a tab bar controller. Buy view and Sell view. But in sell view and in buy view, there are several views each. "List of offers", "offer details", "make offer", etc.

I was thinking of changing the view belonging to the "sell view"-tab on button clicks, but that seems wrong.

What is the correct way to handle this? Should the "buy" and "sell" tabs each be linked to a view, which in turn contains an array of the several subviews list, details, make offer, etc.?

And how do I access the "sell" view from my "offer list" view buttons?

Thx a bunch,
MrB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simpliest form, the following will work

Each tab gets it's own UINavigation controller. Each navigation controller has it's own collection of UIViewControllers.

When the user clicks on a tab they are presented with the corresponding nav controller. Each nav controller could show a UITableViewController that has a selection of sub view controllers to select.

the following is semi-psuedo code.. fyi

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    UIWindow *w = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];;
    self.window = w; //property defined in the .h file
    [w release];



    //add the TabBarControllers view to the window.. this will be presented to the user
    [self.window addSubview:tbc.view];


    //BUT.. the tab bar doesnt have any items to show.. lets solve that

    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // you should have two ViewControllers already created, ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB, or whetever you want to call them.
    // they should both inherit from UITableViewController (for our example)
    // then create two UINavigationControllers, initialize each one with the corresponding ViewController (ViewControllerA and B);
    // add each UINavigationController to our array above




    //assign our view controllers;
    tbc.viewControllers=a;
    [a release];



    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ya. And what's nice about this simple design is that it keeps each primay view with it's own view controller.  Nice MVC pattern.

Comment: Ok one question: I created a new class ClientNavigationController, subclassed of UINavigationController. But there's no xib file. How do I put the navigation controller inside the tab controller? The tab controller only has a field for xib/nib files. Thx.

Comment: Aha, I managed to put in "ClientNavigationController" as the class of the tab. Now the view is empty when I build. So I guess it kind of worked. All this putting-stuff-in-the-right-place in Xcode makes me go crazy. You don't code, you build puzzles.

Comment: Alright, I just read in Apple's doc that UINavigationController is not to be subclassed. I should be using an instance. Where would I create the two instances?

Comment: I have to admit... I do a TON of iphone dev.. and I NEVER use nibs.  Thats just me. Im not saying they are bad or not effective.. I just find it easier to code everything without a nib.  I feel like I have more control of whats going on.

Comment: Ok, so where do I put them in with code? In the myAppDelegate.m file in "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ?

Comment: Thank you. I can already add tabs with images and titles and have them show views. You are right, it is easier to do with code than in Interface Builder. At least you get compile errors, not just link errors!

Comment: Wohoo! This is awesome! I have now created two UINavigationControllers like you suggested and pushed the other view controllers onto them. The back button already works!

Comment: One question though. How do I push new view controllers on it in reaction to the user tapping a button? Cause in the view controller where the button resides, I don't think I have access to the UINavigationController..